# How can I construct a surjection with a kernel $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I construct a surjection from a group $G$ to $S_3$ with the kernel $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ ? I know how to construct the surjection from $S_4$ to $S_3$ with kernel $Z_2 \times Z_2$ (through the conjugation action on products of two-cycles); can I base this on that?

Comment: The simplest approach for a kernel of $H_1$ and an image of $H_2$ is the obvious map $H_1\times H_2\to H_2$. So $G=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times S_3$.

Comment: Trivially, for any groups $G, H$, the projection map $G \times H \to G$ has kernel $\{1\} \times H \cong H$, but this is obviously not as interesting as your example $S_4 \to S_3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hah, that occurred to me as well. Is there a more interesting, group-action motivated one though? I am curious.

Comment: for instance, would the surjection $S_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow S_3$ work?

Comment: @user151882. If you really want something more complicated, you could let $S_3$ act on $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ by permuting the factors and form the semi-direct product.